# Fllutter/Firestore - realtime listening to collections and subcollections

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase collection named 'reviews' with a sub-collection 'clients'.

I am looking to fetch all reviews in realtime with their owners from Firebase Firestore but I got a bit lost when it came to correctly mapping the data and returning the listener's result.

This is 'reviews' model:

```
class Review {
    final String reviewTitle;
    final String reviewContent;
    final String reviewCategory;
    final String reviewTimestamp;
    final int reviewVotesCount;
    final Client client;

    Review(
        {this.reviewTitle,
        this.reviewContent,
        this.reviewCategory,
        this.reviewTimestamp,
        this.reviewVotesCount,
        this.client});
}
```

This is the Service class:

```
class ReviewService {
    var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    var firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    List<Review> fetchAllThreads() {
    Review review;
    Client client;
    List<Thread> mReviewsList = new List<Review>();
    firestoreInstance.collection('reviews').snapshots().listen((result) {
        result.docs.forEach((result) {
             firestoreInstance
               .collection('reviews')
               .doc(result.id)
               .collection('clients')
               .get()
               .then((result) {/*here I get the result.data()*/});
        });
    });
}
```

**Question** after I get `result.data()` how can I map it to my model so I can add the result object to `mReviewsList` and then return `mReviewsList` ?

Comment: You won't be able to return a `List<Review>` directly from `fetchAllThreads` because `listen()` is asynchronous and returns immediately. The callback is invoked some time later after the results of the query are available. You should instead make this function async to return a Future that resolves when the query is complete. You should also use `get()` instead of `snapshots()` to get a single set of results to return.

Comment: But if you do want realtime results over time, you will not be able to return those from the function at all, since a function can only return once. The function should take a callback to receive snapshots as they become available, or return a Stream that can be listened to.  The caller will need to unsubscribe from the stream correctly or it will leak.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a factory constructor in your `Review` class to create it from a Map and same applies for `Client`.

```
  factory Review.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (map == null) return null;
  
    return Review(
      reviewTitle: map['reviewTitle'],
      reviewContent: map['reviewContent'],
      reviewCategory: map['reviewCategory'],
      reviewTimestamp: map['reviewTimestamp'],
      reviewVotesCount: map['reviewVotesCount'],
      client: Client.fromMap(map['client']),
    );
  }
```

*If you're using VS Code, 'Dart Data Class Generator' extension can be handy there, and also there are multiple code generation packages in pub.dev for serialization and deserialization*

Now in the place of your comment, you can do this:

```
mReviewsList.add(Review.fromMap(result.data()));
```

**Update:**

Based on Doug's comment, if you like to map your the data to your model and return a stream, you can create a helper function as follow:

```
 Stream<List<T>> collectionStream<T>({
    @required String path,
    @required T builder(Map<String, dynamic> data),
  }) {
    final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
    final snapshots = reference.snapshots();
    return snapshots
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((snapshot) => builder(snapshot.data())).toList());
  }
```

To use it, simply call it as follow:

```
final stream = collectionStream<Review>(path: "reviews", builder: (data) => Review.fromMap(data));
```

if you like to fetch the data only once, you can create a helper function for that too:

```
Future<List<T>> getDocuments<T>({
  String path,
  @required T builder(Map<String, dynamic> data),
}) async {
  final reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(path);
  final snapshots = await reference.get();
  final docs = snapshots.docs.map((doc) => builder(doc.data())).toList();
  return docs;
}
```

and call it the same way:

```
final reviews = getDocuments<Review>(path: "reviews", builder: (data) => Review.fromMap(data));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this just converts a snapshot to another object. It doesn't address how to return that data to the caller, given that the data is available inside an asynchronous callback.

Comment: @DougStevenson I focused on `how can I map it to my model ` part only, but I updated the answer now to cover the complete question.

Comment: after tweaking here and there, I got it to work your solution seems appropriate, but the only problem now is that it is returned result is empty

Comment: @ThorvaldOlavsen are you using the firestore emulator? If so, try without using the emulator (I tested it locally and it doesn't work with emulator but works fine when connecting to the remote firestore).

Comment: @osaxma yes it works properly on a real device, the only problem now it doesn't return the associated sub-collection, when I try to get `review.owner.username` I get `NULL` if you have any idea about how it can be solved please update your answer

Comment: @ThorvaldOlavsen When you stream a collection, you only receive the documents in that collection (the sub-collections don't get retrieved). If you need to access a sub-collection, you've to query it separately.

Comment: maybe you should add the client data inside the reviews data. Your other option is fire-up two streams and then merge them, maybe with the help of using a library like RxDart.